# Is it always inappropriate to #import more than absolute necessary in Objective-C interfaces?

Tags: objective-c, class, import, forward-declaration

I'm well aware that the general rule of thumb is you should only import what is necessary—base class interfaces, protocol interfaces, etc.—for a class to compile and use `@class` for everything that can be forward-declared. However, I ran into the following scenario in which I felt like `#import` was a more appropriate solution:

```
#import "ClassA.h"      // Previously, @class ClassA;
#import "ClassB.h"      // Previously, @class ClassB;
#import "ClassC.h"      // Unnecessary to forward-declare

@interface ClassD : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassA *  classAObject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassB *  classBObject;
@property (nonatomic, copy)   NSArray * classCObjects;

@end
```

At first, I simply forward-declared `ClassA` and `ClassB` (as the components of `classCObjects` are of `ClassC` only by contract). This was my initial instinct.

But after trying to use `ClassD` elsewhere, I quickly realized that I had to also import `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC` along with `ClassD` everywhere I used it. This seems like something another class shouldn't have to care about when using `ClassD`. My thinking was that, basically, a user of `ClassD` should really only care about importing `ClassD.h` and assume it can work with the entire class without a bunch of other `#import` statements. Given the above approach, I've basically included everything necessary to work within the domain of `ClassD` right in its interface.

Is there a strong reason why this approach is not ideal, except for "you've included more than is absolutely necessary for compilation?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While the strategy you're generally following-- don't import more than necessary--is awesome, classy style and a great thing to aim for in general, don't sweat the tricky cases too much. Just `#import` what you need.

In practice, on a modern machine, the only effect over-`#import`ing will have is to add a few unobservable microseconds to your compile time. Use the developer time you'll save for making your app awesomer. :)

Comment: That's what my realization was, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't violating some more important design principal as a result. Works for me. :)

Comment: `#import` might be the single best improvement over straight C that Obj-C offers. ;) Use it, love it, and don't sweat it. That's how I roll, anyways. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer, one should go forward declaration of classes where ever it is possible. It considerably reduces compilation time on big projects. But spending too much time on where to forward declare isn't any way going to help you design a very good attractive app. So, if you can forward declare *do it* but *it is not a must*.